# Multi-valued Observable and stale data returned by server

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

Working on an `angular 6`application. The scenario is similar to the one described here [Angular HttpClient interceptors](http://Return%20a%20multi-valued%20Observable), similar but not the same:

In my scenario there is no client side cache, server returns data immediately, albeit stale, but the client needs to be updated, even with stale data, on receipt of stale data a second call is made to the server, this time setting `refresh = true` where upon the server may take it's time but will return current data.

When the call finishes second time, the client is refreshed again (this time with fresh information)

This is my attempt, it is working, but feels clunky.

Is there a way to make it better? (more inline with rxjs/reactive way)

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {      

 let stale = false;
 let response: any;

 return next.handle(req)
   .pipe(
     filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
     tap(event => {          
       if (event['body'].expired) {
         stale = true;
       }
       response = event;
     }),
     switchMap(event => {
       if (stale) {
         req.body['refresh'] = true;
         const freshResults$ = next.handle(req);
         return freshResults$.pipe(startWith(response));
       } else {
         return of(response);
       }
     })
   );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
const [ok$, expired$] = next.handle(req).pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse)
    partition((({body}) = !body.expired))
)

return merge(ok$, expired$.pipe(switchMap((response) => {
    const newReq = {...req, body: {...req.body, refresh: true}};
    return next.handle(newReq)/* not sure why you need pipe(startWith(response)) */;
})));
```